# How to figure out how much money was spent for a collection of orders for a particular coin using the Binance API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, bitcoin, binance

Basically imagine a coin like DOT, you could have 5 different buy orders that you put at different times and at different prices and some of them could even be filled partially. Then consider some sell orders that sold some of these coins.

Not you might have 200 coins left after all of these operations. But how can you really figure out how much you really spent for these coins?

Right now I am entering them manually but it's error prone as it's easy to miss orders that are filled but you didn't realize.

I am just trying to calculate PNL % (profits and losses). So if I add the orders manually, of course it works perfectly.

But there must be an automated way to do this.

Going through the order history, I am not sure how to add all of these up. Is this possible? How can I do this? Does binance know how much money is spent in total for a particular coin?

Answer (score -1):

The best way for this to use `myTrades` endpoint https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#account-trade-list-user_data

```
{
    "symbol": "BNBBTC",
    "id": 28457,
    "orderId": 100234,
    "orderListId": -1, //Unless OCO, the value will always be -1
    "price": "4.00000100",
    "qty": "12.00000000",
    "quoteQty": "48.000012",
    "commission": "10.10000000",
    "commissionAsset": "BNB",
    "time": 1499865549590,
    "isBuyer": true,
    "isMaker": false,
    "isBestMatch": true
  }
```

For PNL you need 3 fields from this response `qty`, `price`, and `isBuyer`

Comment: Thanks but how do you deduct the sell orders from this? Because there will be multiple mixed orders.

Comment: `isBuyer === true` it's `BUY` orders. `isBuyer === false` it's `SELL` orders.

Comment: Thanks I know this one. My difficulty was figuring out the PNL for the entire balance for a particular coin but I think I know how to do it now. Basically not about gathering and separating the orders but rather the math behind.